# JavaScript event handler not working when second item is added to a div?

Tags: javascript

So basically when I run this code it adds a button to a div and when you press the button it removes itself as expected.

```js
document.getElementById("inputdiv").innerHTML += '<button type="button" id="remove">X1</button>'
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("remove").remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="inputdiv"></div>
```

However when you add two buttons X1 event handler stops working but X2 works fine?

I believe when the second button is added it some how effects there first button event handler but not sure why?

```js
document.getElementById("inputdiv").innerHTML += '<button type="button" id="remove">X1</button>'
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("remove").remove();
});

document.getElementById("inputdiv").innerHTML += '<button type="button" id="remove2">X2</button>'
document.getElementById("remove2").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("remove2").remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="inputdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` does not append instead reloads the full DOM. That's why the event does not work. You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead:

```js
document.getElementById("inputdiv").innerHTML += '<button type="button" id="remove">X1</button>'
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("remove").remove();
});

document.getElementById("inputdiv").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button type="button" id="remove2">X2</button>');
document.getElementById("remove2").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("remove2").remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="inputdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that answers my question